# Not able to call service using json request

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, wcf

I am new to the WCF and writing my first WCF application.
I am not able to call service from json request

Following are the details of project/solution

I have total 3 projects in my solution
[image: Solution Description]
1. Service Library Project(MyFirstRESTfulService)
2. Host application(WCFService2)
3. Service Client(ServiceClient)

**1. MyFirstRESTfulService**

Class **IEmployeeService.cs**

```
namespace MyFirstRESTfulService
{
    [ServiceContract()]
    public interface IEmployeeService
    {
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Employee", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json )]
        [OperationContract]
        List<Employee> GetAllEmployeeDetails();
    }
}
```

Class **EmployeeService.cs**

```
namespace MyFirstRESTfulService
{
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode= AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed )]
   public  class EmployeeService: IEmployeeService 
    {

       public List <Employee> GetAllEmployeeDetails()
        {
            return EmployeeData.Instance.EmployeeList;
        }
    }
}
```

**2. WCFService2**

**Service.svc**

**Web.config**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyFirstRESTfulService.EmployeeService">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8046/WCFService2/Service.svc" behaviorConfiguration="Web" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyFirstRESTfulService.IEmployeeService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>

        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8046/WCFService2/Service.svc/MyFirstRESTfulService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**3. ServiceClient**

Default.aspx

```
<body>
    <script src="Script/jquery1.9.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        function RefreshPage() {
            var serviceUrl = "http://localhost:8046/WCFService2/Service.svc/MyFirstRESTfulService/GetAllEmployeeDetails";
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: serviceUrl,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    var itemRow = "<table>";
                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        itemRow += "<tr><td>" + item.EmpId + "</td><td>" + item.Fname + "</td></tr>";
                    });
                    itemRow += "</table>";

                    $("#divItems").html(itemRow);

                },
                error: ServiceFailed
            });
        }
        </script>
    </script>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type="button" onclick="RefreshPage()" name="btnRefesh" value="Refresh" />
    <div id="divItems">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

But these things not working at all.While clicking on button nothing is happening.Can you please tell me where I went wrong.

I am getting following error

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Service</title>
    <style>BODY { color: #000000; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; } #content { margin-left: 30px; font-size: .70em; padding-bottom: 2em; } A:link { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:visited { color: #6699cc; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:active { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } .heading1 { background-color: #003366; border-bottom: #336699 6px solid; color: #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 26px; font-weight: normal;margin: 0em 0em 10px -20px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left: 30px;padding-top: 16px;} pre { font-size:small; background-color: #e5e5cc; padding: 5px; font-family: Courier New; margin-top: 0px; border: 1px #f0f0e0 solid; white-space: pre-wrap; white-space: -pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; } table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; font-family: Verdana;} table th { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; font-weight: bold; background-color: #cecf9c;} table td { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; background-color: #e5e5cc;}</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <p class="heading1">Service</p>
      <p>Endpoint not found.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you should be using the webHttpBinding(JSON/POX) instead of the wsHttpBinding(SOAP)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.How can i do webHttpBinding(JSON/POX) in side the web.Config instead of binding="wsHttpBinding"? or any where else

Comment: Also add the 'RequestFormat' part to " [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Employee", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json )]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the webHttpBinding instead of the wsHttpBinding if you want to be able to communicate over HTTP with POX or JSON.

Your config should look something like

```
<services> 
     <service behaviorConfiguration="Default" name="Example.MyService"> 
       <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Example.IServiceContract" /> 
          <host> 
              <baseAddresses> 
                  <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9000/MYService" /> 
              </baseAddresses> 
          </host> 
        </service> 
    </services> 
    <behaviors> 
        <endpointBehaviors> 
            <behavior name="webBehavior"> 
                <webHttp /> 
            </behavior> 
        </endpointBehaviors>
```

Also annotate your operation contracts with "RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json" & "ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json"

Hope this helps,

Comment: Still I am not able to get the correct values.Now i am getting the error "Endpoint not found.".I will update the new web config in above code section.

Comment: change your javascript to point to the correct location:
"http://localhost:8046/WCFService2/Service.svc/Employee"
instead of "http://localhost:8046/WCFService2/Service.svc/MyFirstRESTfulService/GetAllEmployeeDetails".

The endpoint of the service is determined in the config as 'http://localhost:8046/WCFService2/Service.svc' and your Operation's URI template is "Employee".